# How to clear docker-compose image name in VS2017

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

After a Visual studio update I can't start the project in debug mode when docker-compose is set as startup project.
It fails on

[image]

tried so far:

1. clean on docker-compose project
2. deleting the .vs, bin and obj folders
3. removing and re-adding the docker-compose project
4. deleting the whole project folder and getting it back from github
5. deleting the vs debug folder under the `User` folder
6. complete `docker system prune -a` thus removing any images running or not

I am completely out of ideas short of reinstalling the whole VS2017 again, but that seems like an overkill.

Does anyone know where this image name is cached and how to refresh/delete that so that it doesn't try to find that image running again

here is the startup output in docker console:

```
========== Debugging ==========
docker-compose  -f "C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5497340922178811047 --no-ansi config
services:
  integration-db:
    container_name: projectname-integration-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pguser
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
    image: postgres
    ports:
    - published: 5432
      target: 5432
    volumes:
    - /tmp/customer/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
  customer.projectname.api.webhost:
    build:
      context: C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service
      dockerfile: Customer.projectname.Api.WebHost/Dockerfile
      target: base
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: Host=integration-db;Port=5432;Username=pguser;Password=pguser;Database=dm;MaxPoolSize=150;
      DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER: '1'
      NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
    image: customer.projectname.api.webhost:dev
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: ' --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages
        --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Customer.projectname.Api.WebHost.dll'
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: /bin/bash -c "if PID=$$(pidof
        -x dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: dotnet
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: /app
    ports:
    - target: 80
    volumes:
    - C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service\Customer.projectname.Api.WebHost:/app:rw
    - C:\Users\ZaakSlezak\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:ro
    - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages:ro
    - C:\Users\ZaakSlezak\.nuget\packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
  test:
    build:
      context: C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile-test
    command: ./devops/scripts/test.sh
    volumes:
    - C:\dev\src\ps-projectname-service:/app:rw
version: '3.4'
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "name=dockercompose5497340922178811047_customer.projectname.api.webhost_" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
```

Comment: What is the result of your `docker ps ...` command?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk

`λ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES`

I did also the `docker system prune -a`

Comment: Did you try `docker-compose kill`?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk yes I did, there is definitely nothing running anywhere, the problem seems to be this cached image name that I cant find stored anywhere and delete it

Comment: Ok, did you try to remove images?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk yes I did, I don't have any images, I can even run it using docker-compose directly, but then I can't debug service running in docker from Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I got stuck in this loop because one of the services in my docker-compose that was being used to run unit tests did not have an image associated with it.
removing it from docker-compose or adding the image: fixed the problem.